# Is there a safe way to reuse the same code for immutable and mutable variants of a function?

Tags: generics, reference, rust, immutability, mutability

I did a bit of searching, and found [this Reddit post from four years ago](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2a721y/a_safe_way_to_reuse_the_same_code_for_immutable/), but other than unsafe code:

```
fn find_mut <'a> (&'a mut self, elem: &T) -> Option<&'a mut Node<T>> {
    unsafe{std::mem::transmute(self.find(elem))}
}
```

or a macro, I can't think of any ways to do this.

Alternative restatements of the problem:

- Make a function generic over mutability.
- Mutability modifier polymorphism.

Is there a way to do this now?

---

Motivation, just in case this is another XY problem: I'd like to write a function that processes a vector of references, reading them but not modifying them, and I would like to use those functions both in cases where I will have `&T`s and `&mut T`s.

Comment: Note that transmuting an immutable reference to a mutable reference is **always** unsafe, [don't do it ever](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/transmutes.html).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the motivation you described at the end of your message, my understanding is that you'd like to inspect `Vec<&T>` and `Vec<&mut T>` with one function and without modifying the underlying `T`s. Does this do what you want? Note that I used references to slices because it's more idiomatic as parameter than references to vectors as the latter coerce to the former.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=455a1ee0a5d1c362167eed983df7cb4e)

```rust
use std::ops::Deref;

struct Foo;

fn do_stuff(_: &Foo) {}

fn process<T>(v: &[T])
where
    T: Deref<Target = Foo>,
{
    for x in v.iter().map(|x| x.deref()) {
        do_stuff(x);
    }
}

fn main() {
    process(&[&Foo]);
    process(&[&mut Foo]);
}
```

Using `Borrow` instead of `Deref`, you can also pass `&[Foo]`.